# How do I test GCP budget monitoring notifications?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How do I confirm I've set up GCP budget monitoring notifications correctly?

I've created a test budget w/ some thresholdPercents and an email based monitoringNotificationChannel.

Ideally, I'd like to burn a single $1 dollar (or even a little more) to
trigger the .01 thresholdPercent notification (1% of 100USD = $1).

But I don't what/how to run/deploy in GCP anything that will do that.

Here's my test budget:

```
PS C:\TEST> gcloud billing budgets create 
--filter-projects=projects/testprj 
--billing-account=0123456-789012-345678 --display-name="MYAWSUM-TESTBUDGET" 
--budget-amount=100.00USD 
--threshold-rule=percent=0.01 --threshold-rule=percent=0.50 
--start-date=2022-07-01 --end-date=2022-09-30 
--notifications-rule-monitoring-notification-channels=projects/testprj/notificationChannels/0987654321

Created [b7d51ec4-1234-4825-a95e-b2c99b89b006].


PS C:\TEST> gcloud billing budgets list --billing-account=0123456-789012-345678
amount:
  specifiedAmount:
    currencyCode: USD
    units: '100'
budgetFilter:
  creditTypesTreatment: INCLUDE_ALL_CREDITS
  customPeriod:
    endDate:
      day: 30
      month: 9
      year: 2022
    startDate:
      day: 1
      month: 7
      year: 2022
  projects:
  - projects/624270349538
displayName: MYAWSUM-TESTBUDGET
etag: '1658773026868358'
name: billingAccounts/0123456-789012-3456782/budgets/b7d51ec4-1234-4825-a95e-b2c99b89b006
notificationsRule:
  monitoringNotificationChannels:
  - projects/testprj/notificationChannels/0987654321
thresholdRules:
- spendBasis: CURRENT_SPEND
  thresholdPercent: 0.01
- spendBasis: CURRENT_SPEND
  thresholdPercent: 0.5
```

Comment: Besides the command that you have run to show the currently active budget alerts, there is no mechanism to deliberately test budget alert triggers. If you’d like to have that feature implemented in a possible future release, you can create a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187201&template=0) for that functionality.